# What is equivalent to a "midterm" if it happens at 1/3?

Tags: phrase-usage, terminology

An event that occurs halfway through is referred to a midterm event. Like a midterm exam. What if it occurs at 1/3 of the time, or at 2/3.

Comment: And at 0.49999? [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mid) says of **mid**: "Of or in the middle part or position of a range" and it also says "In the middle of, **in the course of.**" Perhaps you could say "part way through".

Comment: I've taken plenty of courses with exams 1/3 and 2/3 of the way through, and they were always just called midterms. (Ususlly "first midterm" and "second midterm" respectively).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A third of the way through, " or

"At the one third point"(little awkward),

"Around the one third mark", (slightly informal)

Halfway is common enough to be used directly.  Other fractions can follow:

"A quarter of the way though"

"A fifth of the way,"

"At the 15% mark,"

etc.

For exams, Midterm is a special name.  There are no "tri-term" exams and such.  Just Midterms and Finals.  Outside of tests, elections, or perhaps pregnancy, I've not heard Midterm used.

Answer (score 1):

"Mid" does not have to be the exact middle of something. Two dictionaries I checked have "at or near the middle" and "at the middle of or during".